# Using a Class with a Form

Tags: c#

I am getting an error on lines 44 and 50.
It says:

> No overload for method 'GetCarData' takes 1 arguments

Alright, so my task is to create an application that displays 3 main features: year, make, and speed of a car. The year and make are inputted with textboxes and the speed starts at 0.

There is an accelerate button which is supposed to add 5 to the speed every time it is pressed and a brake button which decreases the speed by 5 every time it is pressed.

I am having trouble using the class and form together to display the results. I need to display in a messagebox the make, year, and speed. I have been sitting here for hours and I am getting nowhere.

Any and all help is much appreciated. I have never worked with classes before.

Here is the form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Car_Class_BBrantley
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Car myCar;

        public Form1()
        {
            myCar = new Car();

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void GetCarData()
        {
            try {
                myCar.Make = txtMake.Text;

                myCar.Year = int.Parse(txtModel.Text);

                myCar.Speed = 0;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Concat("Must enter a valid make and year model for the car. ", ex.Message, "\r\n", ex.StackTrace));
            }
        }

        private void btnAcc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetCarData();
            myCar.AccSpeed(5);
            MessageBox.Show(" Your car is a " + myCar.Year + myCar.Make + " and it is     traveling " + myCar.Speed + " mph. ");
        }

        private void btnBrake_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetCarData();
            myCar.DecSpeed(5);
            MessageBox.Show(" Your car is a " + myCar.Year + myCar.Make + " and it is     traveling " + myCar.Speed + " mph. ");
        }
    }
}
```

If you would like to see the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Car_Class_BBrantley
{
    class Car
    {
        private int year;
        private string make;
        private int speed;

        public Car()
        {
            this.year = 1994;
            this.make = "Ford";
            this.speed = 0;
        }

        public Car(string make, int year, int speed)
        {
            this.year = year;
            this.make = make;
            this.speed = speed;
        }

        public string Make
        {
            get { return make; }
            set { make = value; }
        }

        public int Year
        {
            get { return Year; }
            set { Year = value; }
        }

        public int Speed
        {
            get { return speed; }
            set { speed = value; }
        }

        public void AccSpeed(int speedIncrement)
        {
            //Add check for speed limit ranges
            Speed += speedIncrement;
        }

        public void DecSpeed(int speedDecrement)
        {
            //Add check for speed limit ranges
            Speed -= speedDecrement;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Save and re-compile. The message says `'Car_Class_BBrantley.Form1.myCar()' must declare a body` but you don't have `myCar()` any more, only `myCar`.

Comment: Your code looks fine as-is.  Are these two classes in the same assembly?  If not, `Car` should be public, but you'd get a different error in that case.

Comment: Not sure it would make a difference, but you should `new` the `Car` after `InitializeComponent()`.  Winforms gets mad when you put things before that.

Comment: Side note: not sure what your requirements are but I'd rethink this design. I'd create an interface `ICar` with methods `Accelerate()` and `Decelarate` and then would create different car classes based on the interface. This makes your life so much easier.

Comment: @ClickRick that error is now gone, but I edited the post to show a new error that now occurs...

Comment: @PoweredByOrange The OP isn't even getting the basics working yet. Let's take one step at a time.

Comment: Your `Year` property is declared incorrectly (it is recursive). Lowercase the value you are setting and getting in the property (e.g. `return Year` => `return year`).

Comment: Then look at the calls to `GetCarData();` and check that they are the same in your code as on here, with nothing between the brackets.

Comment: @ClickRick Thats why I said it's a side note ;)

Comment: @PoweredByOrange I have more side notes here than space in the margin to write them ;)

Comment: Have we moved through 3 different questions just in edits alone with this one?

Comment: Only 2 questions so far, but at least 4 (useful) answers.

Comment: It's worth repeating what @adrianbanks said earlier about your `Year` property - the get and set code should use the lower- case `year` inside them, otherwise it'll go recursive when they're called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the error says

> No overload for method 'GetCarData' takes 1 arguments

then look at the calls you make to `GetCarData` and check that they don't try to pass a parameter (argument) to it.  It's declared as

```
private void GetCarData()
```

which is good, and the two calls (lines 44 and 50) are consistent with that:

```
GetCarData();
```

so make sure that the code on your computer matches what's here, save it, and re-compile.